# VBA Excel Assigning an universal condition to textboxes

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, output, universal

So I have a userform with a set of textboxes. In general I am taking their inputs and printing to a textfile.

**User Screen:**

[image: UserScreen]

**Current Output:**

[image: output]

So I have code that prints the three values in a line in a txt file.
Box1.Value + Box2.Value + Box3.Value etc.

The issue is when the user DOESN'T enter anything. Based on how this text file is read either the correct code OR just something like spaces or null equivalent to the max length of the text box.

**Current Code:**

```
If Len(Box1.Value) < Box1.MaxLength Then
Box1.Value = Space(Box1.MaxLength)
End If
```

**Desired Output:**

[image: goodoutput]

Now what if I want this to work for **ALL TEXT BOXES**. If a bad entry (less than the desired length) or no entry - then all textboxes occupy their max length. This would really help standardize the userform and save a lot of lines of code. (currently have ***15 different text boxes***).

Is there something like this in VBA? Can I put all the ***textboxes in an array*** in VBA?

----------------------------------After Tim's Answer----------------------------

**Test Case**

[image: Test]

**Test Code**

```
Dim UserEntry As String


Private Sub Check_Click()

If Len(TestBox.Value) < TestBox.MaxLength Then
TestBox.Value = Space(TestBox.MaxLength)
End If

UserEntry = TestBox.Value
TestCase.TestCaseLabel.Caption = UserEntry
End Sub
Private Sub Export_Click()

Dim myFile As String
myFile = "C:\Reformatted.txt"
Open myFile For Output As #1

If Len(TestBox.Value) < TestBox.MaxLength Then
TestBox.Value = Space(TestBox.MaxLength)
End If

UserEntry = TestBox.Value
Print #1, UserEntry

Close #1
Shell "C:\Windows\Notepad.exe C:\Reformatted.txt", 1
End Sub

Function ValueIfMaxLength(tb As TextBox) As String

    ValueIfMaxLength = IIf(tb.Value = tb.MaxLength, tb.Value, Space(tb.MaxLength))

End Function
```

Comment: That code will replace any value which isn't of a maximum length - is that what you want?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yeah every textbox has its own maxlength programmed in. So I was  one if else statement that takes one of all the textboxes and prints blanks if the user doesnt enter a max length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a function to simplify your code.
Something like:

```
Function ValueOrDefault(tb as msforms.Textbox) As String
                     'assumed padding with spaces on right...
    ValueOrDefault = Left(tb.Value & Space(tb.MaxLength), tb.MaxLength)

End Function
```

EDIT: If only "maxlength" values are valid...

```
Function ValueIfMaxLength(tb as msforms.Textbox) As String

    ValueIfMaxLength = IIf(Len(tb.Value) = tb.MaxLength, _
                           tb.Value, Space(tb.MaxLength))
    ''uncomment the next line if you want the textbox content to be updated
    'tb.Value = ValueIfMaxLength

End Function
```

Example usage:

```
Private Sub Export_Click()

    Const myFile As String = "C:\Reformatted.txt"

    Open myFile For Output As #1
    Print #1, ValueIfMaxLength(TestBox)
    Close #1
    Shell "C:\Windows\Notepad.exe " & myFile, 1

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Tim, I declared this function outside of my subs. Only issue is when I try to run it where my previous If statements were : MaxLengthCheck (Box1) VBA gives me an error. What to do?

Comment: You'll have to edit your question and include the code you have (or at least a representative part of it)

Comment: I added a test case The actual program just uses multiple of these text boxes. I have my work around. I tried implementing your code some ways and all return error. How to work with this function is the question.

Comment: Sorry - I had a couple errors in there: see my updates.  That's what happens if i post without testing.

Comment: its alive! Thanks for troubleshooting. Appreciate it! :)

Comment: looks like msforms.textbox was the key part